# Cannot get login to work for ODBC driver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am trying to set up an ODBC driver to SQL Server 2000 and cannot what I am doing wrong. The error I get is `sqlstate 28000` and `error 18456 failed login`.

Here are the steps I took:

- create a username under computer management
- then in enterprise manager I create login by going to `security->login new login`
- From there I browse to the user I created in computer management and windows nt is selected as well as grant access
- then went to database and rolls and gave it read and write permissions for a few databases. The default database is set to master. Everything seems to work just fine up to this point.

Then I go to the ODBC manager and then SysDSN then add and I pick SQL Server. From here I name the DSN, pick the server that has both the windows username and the SQL Server on it and click next.

Then I click SQL Server authentication and enter the username and password, and checked to make sure it was right at least 20 times, and then I get the `18456 error`.

Am I missing a step, what happened?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx. It gives you details on how to read the error log and determine what your issue with "error 18456" is.

Comment: @TheCapn I went to enterprise manager management->sql server logs->current error log. I was not able to find error 18456 anywhere in the log. Does this mean the ODBC can't find the database, or does the error log need to told to catch those types of errors.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set up a windows user, not a SQL user, so use Windows authentication in your connection, not SQL User.

This will use whatever you are logged into windows as to connect to the SQL Server. This is 'trusted' authentication, which means you dno't have to remember a zillion passwords, it uses your current one.

If, as I suspect, this is not what you want, then you should create a SQL User on SQL Server, not a windows one. In this case you only create a user name and password in SQL Server, not in Computer Management.

Creation of SQL Users are often disabled by default so you may need to change your server configuration to allow for it.

I always recommend using Windows users not SQL Users, but ifyou are not in an Active Directory environment then SQL Users are fine.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!! this has been driving me crazy all day! I simply deleted the windows user and recreated the database login as standard and it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out :)